# how can i create a new layer using a script in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i need function that goes through all the existing layer names and find if my layer is there and if not then the code need to add the given layer to the layer list

i tried this code this [unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/adding-layer-by-script.41970/)

```
    void CreateLayer()
{
    SerializedObject tagManager = new SerializedObject(AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("ProjectSettings/TagManager.asset")[0]);

    SerializedProperty layers = tagManager.FindProperty("layers");
    if (layers == null || !layers.isArray)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Can't set up the layers.  It's possible the format of the layers and tags data has changed in this version of Unity.");
        Debug.LogWarning("Layers is null: " + (layers == null));
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 8; i < 31; i++)
    {
        SerializedProperty layerSP = layers.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
        if (layerSP.stringValue == "MyLayer")
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 8; i < 31; i++)
    {
        SerializedProperty layerSP = layers.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
        if (layerSP.stringValue != "")
        {
            layerSP.stringValue = "MyLayer";
            break;
        }
    }

    tagManager.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
```

but it dosen't work for me

by the way i'm using unity 5.6.3

if anybody knows the answer please share

Comment: You must be re-working an old game :)

Comment: ... any why not simply use the [one that already exists](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TagManager.html)?

Answer (score 1):

i found out this one over [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/create-tags-and-layers-in-the-editor-using-script-both-edit-and-runtime-modes.732119/) this answer will work only in editor and will not work in build

create a new c# script add this code into it

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Layers
{
private static int maxTags = 10000;
private static int maxLayers = 31;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public void AddNewLayer(string name)
{
    CreateLayer(name);
}

public void DeleteLayer(string name)
{
    RemoveLayer(name);
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/// <summary>
/// Adds the layer.
/// </summary>
/// <returns><c>true</c>, if layer was added, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
/// <param name="layerName">Layer name.</param>
public static bool CreateLayer(string layerName)
{
    // Open tag manager
    SerializedObject tagManager = new SerializedObject(AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("ProjectSettings/TagManager.asset")[0]);
    // Layers Property
    SerializedProperty layersProp = tagManager.FindProperty("layers");
    if (!PropertyExists(layersProp, 0, maxLayers, layerName))
    {
        SerializedProperty sp;
        // Start at layer 9th index -> 8 (zero based) => first 8 reserved for unity / greyed out
        for (int i = 8, j = maxLayers; i < j; i++)
        {
            sp = layersProp.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
            if (sp.stringValue == "")
            {
                // Assign string value to layer
                sp.stringValue = layerName;
                Debug.Log("Layer: " + layerName + " has been added");
                // Save settings
                tagManager.ApplyModifiedProperties();
                return true;
            }
            if (i == j)
                Debug.Log("All allowed layers have been filled");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Debug.Log ("Layer: " + layerName + " already exists");
    }
    return false;
}

public static string NewLayer(string name)
{
    if (name != null || name != "")
    {
        CreateLayer(name);
    }

    return name;
}

/// <summary>
/// Removes the layer.
/// </summary>
/// <returns><c>true</c>, if layer was removed, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
/// <param name="layerName">Layer name.</param>
public static bool RemoveLayer(string layerName)
{

    // Open tag manager
    SerializedObject tagManager = new SerializedObject(AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("ProjectSettings/TagManager.asset")[0]);

    // Tags Property
    SerializedProperty layersProp = tagManager.FindProperty("layers");

    if (PropertyExists(layersProp, 0, layersProp.arraySize, layerName))
    {
        SerializedProperty sp;

        for (int i = 0, j = layersProp.arraySize; i < j; i++)
        {

            sp = layersProp.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);

            if (sp.stringValue == layerName)
            {
                sp.stringValue = "";
                Debug.Log("Layer: " + layerName + " has been removed");
                // Save settings
                tagManager.ApplyModifiedProperties();
                return true;
            }

        }
    }

    return false;

}
/// <summary>
/// Checks to see if layer exists.
/// </summary>
/// <returns><c>true</c>, if layer exists, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
/// <param name="layerName">Layer name.</param>
public static bool LayerExists(string layerName)
{
    // Open tag manager
    SerializedObject tagManager = new SerializedObject(AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("ProjectSettings/TagManager.asset")[0]);

    // Layers Property
    SerializedProperty layersProp = tagManager.FindProperty("layers");
    return PropertyExists(layersProp, 0, maxLayers, layerName);
}
/// <summary>
/// Checks if the value exists in the property.
/// </summary>
/// <returns><c>true</c>, if exists was propertyed, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
/// <param name="property">Property.</param>
/// <param name="start">Start.</param>
/// <param name="end">End.</param>
/// <param name="value">Value.</param>
private static bool PropertyExists(SerializedProperty property, int start, int end, string value)
{
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        SerializedProperty t = property.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
        if (t.stringValue.Equals(value))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

and to create a layer

```
new Layers().AddNewLayer("PP");
```